# Can I use a Method instead of Lambda expression with extra parameters

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have an inline lambda expression that I would like to use throughout my application. I just can't seem to find a reference on how to do this with more parameters than the element being tested. Here is a quick example of what I currently have.

```vb
Private Sub Test()
    Dim List As New List(Of String) From {"Joe", "Ken", "Bob", "John"}
    Dim Search As String = "*Jo*"
    Dim Result = List.Where(Function(Name) Name Like Search)
End Sub
```

I know the `IEnumerable.Where` accepts a method with the element type as a parameter and a returning boolean.

```vb
Private Sub Test()
    Dim List As New List(Of String) From {"Joe", "Ken", "Bob", "John"}
    Dim Search As String = "*Jo*"
    Dim Result = List.Where(AddressOf FindName)
End Sub

Private Function FindName(Name As String) As Boolean
    Return Name Like "*Jo*"
End Function
```

I would like to pass the Search variable into FindName as well. I just can't seem to get the syntax figured accomplish this. The only working solution I've come up with is passing everything to a function to perform the original statement.

```vb
Private Sub Test()
    Dim List As New List(Of String) From {"Joe", "Ken", "Bob", "John"}
    Dim Search As String = "*Jo*"
    Dim Result = FindName(List, Search)
End Sub

Private Function FindName(List As IEnumerable(Of String), Search As String) As IEnumerable(Of String)
    Return List.Where(Function(Name) Name Like Search)
End Function
```

Don't feel obligated to answer in VB.

Comment: Shortened my [delegate approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9036948/284240).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The nice thing with lambda expressions is that they allow *closures* to automatically capture variables that are local to your scope. For example (pardon the C#):

```
List.Where(i => FindName(i, Search));
```

In the above code, the `Search` variable is actually being encapsulated in a *closure*. If you want to just pass a method, you'll have to simulate what closures do with an actual class structure:

```
public class NameFinder
{
    private string _search;
    public NameFinder(string search) {
        _search = search;
    }
    public bool Match(string item) {
        // C# equivalent of "return item LIKE _search"
    }
}

// Usage
var nameFinder = new NameFinder(Search);
List.Where(nameFinder.Match);
```

However, this strategy is only useful in a small subset of cases. I find it's usually best to just use a lambda expression that passes the appropriate variables into the function that does all the work.

Answer (score 1):

I would use an extension method:-

```
Module Module1

    Sub main()
        Dim List As New List(Of String) From {"Joe", "Ken", "Bob", "John"}
        Dim Search As String = "*Jo*"
        Dim Result = List.FindName(Search)
    End Sub


End Module

Public Module Extensions

    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
    Public Function FindName(List As IEnumerable(Of String), Search As String) As IEnumerable(Of String)

        Return List.Where(Function(Name) Name Like Search)

    End Function

End Module
```

Comment: Having read your question again i'm not 100% sure this is what your actually after?

Comment: What I was after may not exist after reading the answers so far. But the extension will clean up the separate function, so in my case, the extension will work well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [Func(Of T, TResult) Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx) even with multiple parameters:

```
Dim names = {"Joe", "Ken", "Bob", "John", "Otto"}
Dim matchesPattern As Func(Of String, String, Boolean) =
    Function(input, searchPattern) input Like searchPattern
Dim results = names.Where(Function(name) matchesPattern(name, "?o*"))
' returns "Joe", "Bob" and "John" '
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can pass in more arguments to the `Where` method, but you could set your search parameter as a class member which the `FindName` method can access. For example (I'll write this in C# as that is what I'm more familiar with):

```
string search = "Ken";

private void Test()
{
    var list = new List<string>() { "Joe", "Ken", "Bob", "John" };
    // Set search member to whatever you need before calling query
    search = "Joe";
    var result = list.Where(FindName);
}

private bool FindName(string name)
{
    // Predicate method will compare against whatever class member is set to
    return name == search;
}
```

Comment: This is bad practice. You are using global state to solve a local problem. This can easily lead to problems. If you return the result for example you have no control over when the query is actually executed in the meantime the variable could change. Same problem if you have multiple threads. Use LINQ directly or an extension method like others suggested.

Comment: Thinking through what you said I can see what you mean and now agree with you, would never work in a multi-threaded context either.